# Using Java Streams with ORMLite

Tags: java, jersey, ormlite

I recently decided to switch my application (a fairly simple RESTful suite of APIs) to use Java Streams for many of the resource endpoints, as an example:

```
@ForeignCollectionField
protected ForeignCollection<>   people;
@GET
public Set<Person> getStaff() {
        return people.stream()
                .filter(n -> (n.role & Person.ROLE_STAFF) == Person.ROLE_STAFF)
                .map(n -> n.left)
                .collect(Collectors.toSet());
}
```

In this case - and most others - people is a lazy [`ForeignCollection`](http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/com/j256/ormlite/dao/ForeignCollection.html)

However, this has resulted in various errors showing up with lots of concurrent requests:

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
        at java.lang.System.arraycopy(Native Method)
        at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.com.read.Buffer.getLengthEncodedBytes(Buffer.java:318)
        at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.com.read.resultset.ColumnInformation.getString(ColumnInformation.java:235)
        at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.com.read.resultset.ColumnInformation.getName(ColumnInformation.java:251)
        at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.com.read.dao.ColumnNameMap.getIndex(ColumnNameMap.java:90)
        at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.com.read.resultset.SelectResultSet.findColumn(SelectResultSet.java:1368)
        at com.j256.ormlite.jdbc.JdbcDatabaseResults.findColumn(JdbcDatabaseResults.java:103)
        at com.j256.ormlite.field.FieldType.resultToJava(FieldType.java:826)
        at com.j256.ormlite.stmt.mapped.BaseMappedQuery.mapRow(BaseMappedQuery.java:44)
        at com.j256.ormlite.stmt.SelectIterator.getCurrent(SelectIterator.java:297)
        at com.j256.ormlite.stmt.SelectIterator.nextThrow(SelectIterator.java:168)
        at com.j256.ormlite.stmt.SelectIterator.next(SelectIterator.java:181)
        at java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:116)
        at java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801)
        at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481)
        at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471)
        at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:708)
        at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
        at java.util.stream.LongPipeline.reduce(LongPipeline.java:438)
        at java.util.stream.LongPipeline.sum(LongPipeline.java:396)
        at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.count(ReferencePipeline.java:526)
```

I'm using Jersey as the framework, some of the API calls use [`@ManagedAsync`](https://jersey.github.io/apidocs/latest/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/server/ManagedAsync.html), some don't. There are no @Singletons. [`Dao`](http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/com/j256/ormlite/dao/Dao.html) objects are shared and an LRU cache exists (shared between all Dao objects)

My question: Why am I getting these weird errors? Does nORMlite support the use of Streams? If so, how do I ensure safety?

I have tried this:

```
try (final CloseableWrappedIterable<PeopleToClub> p = people.getWrappedIterable()) {
  if (asStream(p.iterator()).filter(n -> n.left.getId() == user.getPerson().getId()
    && n.role == Person.ROLE_STAFF).count() > 0) {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
} catch (final IOException e) {
  return false;
}
```

However the "random" errors still exist.

The persistence layer is MariaDB, so concurrent access there should not be a problem (plus, it is SELECT only)

Comment: My guess is that either ForeignCollection isn't thread-safe and you're sharing it between threads, leading to unpredictible behavior, or the mariadb driver is buggy, or both. Unrelated, but it's quite strange to filter persistent data in memory rather than using a database query.

Comment: Because ORMlite populates the ForeignCollection, all the rows are already there, so for simple filtering I wasn't too bothered, plus it was an opportunity for learning Streams. For joins and the like, queries are used.

Comment: Hmm, I don't know much about ORMLite, but given the name of the collection, and given the stack trace, The collection isn't populated. It looks like a lazy collection that reads all the people from the database when you iterate on it. So your getStaff() method actually loads every person from the database.